# Why: Element X not allowed as child of element Y in this context

Tags: html, validation

Can someone explain to me why does HTML validator give me this error? I understand that for cases like block-elements ie (div) cannot be within inline elements like  or  which makes perfect sense but if I were to make custom elements named  and  and used both within another custom one I created called , would I just disregard this error? I assume this is fine but HTML validator doesnt handle custom elements correctly?

Im asking as I am required to use the HTML Validator for a class project and I have to ensure theres no errors but I personally think this makes structurizing my html counter-intuitive even though formatting it as such displays correctly on the page.. Sample: http://potion.x10host.com/blog/posts/runescape-username-checker.html

Structure:

```html
<comment>
    <author>Betty</author>
    <description>Some comment.</description>
</comment>
```

To fix this I am forced to use classes with Divs... which makes organization look horrible.

Comment: Your elements are not valid custom elements. Anyways, the HTML validator does not recognize custom elements as valid yet.

Comment: Ah.... I suppose I will have to email my professor about that then. Thank you. @Oriol

Comment: Looks like XML. https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html#comments

Comment: @zer00ne yeah. I am building a webpage right now and I really hate using the Div class="" as it get's messy so is it fine to use elements like this within HTML? I do plan to parse XML data as well so good point

Comment: No, it would be a disaster, but as Oriol has stated, it's possible with custom elements. Which is possible with [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/)